# Set Interval on an array in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, setinterval

I'm trying to use the `setInterval()` function in order to change text to the user every 3 seconds.

I tried looping with for loop but that doesn't work - I see the 'test 03' and that's it.

I can't find a solution.

```js
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  items = ['test 01', 'test 02', 'test 03'];
  currentItem: any;
  private interval;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.currentItem = this.items[i];
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
{{ currentItem }}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way instead.

`pointer` points to the current content you want to display. With each interval pointer gets increased by 1 until it has a value > 2. Then it starts with 0 again.

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  items = ['test 01', 'test 02', 'test 03'];
  currentItem: any;
  private pointer: number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.currentItem = this.items[this.pointer];
        this.pointer++;
        if (this.pointer > 2) { this.pointer = 0 };
      }, 3000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why was this answer voted down? May the person who did this please state the nature of his or her problem with my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot! how can i make the change be more smooth? like fade effect or something like that? @Lynx 242

Comment: You're welcome. To achieve fading effects plain interpolation won't work. This is usually done with CSS using, for example, 2 overlapping labels. And while the one label fades out the other fades in. But I have no example at hand I could give you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  items = ['test 01', 'test 02', 'test 03'];
  currentItem: any;
  private interval;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.currentItem = this.items[i];
      }, 3000 * i);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
{{ currentItem }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with rxjs,

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  timer(0, 3000)
    .pipe(
      tap(v => {
        this.currentItem = this.items[v%3]
      })
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
}
```

less code, no loop, no fancy logic involved :)

You can do even better with

```
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
  private timer$ = timer(0, 3000);
  ngOnInit() {
    // for loop can be completely removed
  } 
}
```

and in html, use

```
{{ items[(timer$ | async) % 3] }}
```

so you literally just use 1 line of code to do the same thing by leveraging async pipe and rxjs, and forget about the ugly for-loop.

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5prrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts